# What is the risk of form action attribute in asp net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to know the possible risks of having a form with action attribute in asp.net mvc environment?

For example; a create view has < form action="/Person/Create"  ...> on html markup.

Can anybody send a post to  mydomain.com/Person/Create  with fiddler(for example) ?

It is very similar in Jquery ajax scripts as well.  The post or get method's name is visible on html mark up. Everbody can see the html source code of my page. It means everbody can see my actions' name.

How can I have a secure approach about this issue?

Off course I can have Bind attributes on httppost action. But My wish is to make my actions' names secret or to have a best practise idea. (If possible)

Thanks for everything.

Comment: This is not related to ASP.NET MVC or jQuery. Someplace on the client you have to store where you will send your data to. You can try to mask it, hide it, obfuscate it, but at the end of the day it needs to come from client and client is accessible to you.

Comment: If your client calls the server, people will be able to intercept the URLs. There shouldn't be anything that needs to be hidden there. You should focus on making the endpoints secure based on the user permissions instead. It shouldn't matter how somebody calls the method, just that they passed valid data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hide your actions.

Avoid unauthorized access by performing, well, authorization.

Prevent manipulation of authorized people from performing actions unwillingly (aka XSRF attacks) by using anti-request-forgery tokens (as in @Moby's Stunt Double's answer).

Comment: allright, what if the authorized user makes post by fiddler for 100000(or more) times to one of my action?

Comment: @oneNiceFriend that means you let him to do that, (he is authorized). if authorized people are subject to limitations, you have to enforce those limitations (such as 1 req per minute etc).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot hide your actions, but you can accomplish a rudimentary security policy in this regard using ASP.NET's built in Anti Forgery Tokens. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175(v=vs.118).aspx

In your form, place a token with the built in HTML Helper:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Then on your action, place a corresponding attribute:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit()
```

Now you should not be able to simulate a POST request against your controller actions.

...and as Sedat correctly points out below: absolutely and obviously, yes, your actions should always be secured via authorize attributes on your actions, controllers or other deeper mechanisms, if you don't want them anonymously executed by the general public.

Comment: That only works against XSRF attacks though. It does not prevent a person to POST a request to the same action. Someone can still retrieve a forgery token from the cookie, send the POST request using the token, you know like the user himself. To protect actions performed against unknown people proper authorization must be performed.

Comment: I always promote the use of both, Sedat. Any small thing (and by small thing, I mean CSRF tokens as above, not authorisation of requests) we can do to make life difficult for would-be crackers is cool by me.

Answer (score 1):

Theres no need to hide that information, you want the client-side to know where to send data. How they do that isn't up to you, via Browser, Fiddler or from another client-side program. More important is, that the Actions, which result from that GET or POST, are secure. Bind attributes e.g. protect you against overposting.

[Emilio's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34098932/5636998) solution obscures your actions names, which is cool for better readability of URLs but doesn't make it more secure, because now an attacker will see the public names and they will be routed to your action anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't now if this is what you are referring to.
But if you don't want a client user to know your Action Name you could change it with the ActionName attribute for actions:

```
public class ProductsController {

    [ActionName("PublicName")]
    public ActionResult SecretName() {
        return View();
    }

}
```

The url for navigating from the client would be http://yoursite/Products/PublicName instead of http://yoursite/Product/SecretName

You can not hide your action completely. Because you have fiddler you could see any request done from the client to the server so you could know the name of the action in this way.